Ceiling Fan Junction Box
I am trying to install a new ceiling fan but one of the studs from the electrical box is busted up and won’t accept a screw. Is there anyway to replace or fix this without replacing the entire fan box? If I have to replace the entire fan box, how the heck do I get the old one out with no access to it from above.

Pictures will help us and you so we know exactly what you mean.  If by stud, you mean a screw hole, might be able to drill out to next size and tap.

I added a picture. As you can see the screw hole on the right is messed up and unable to accept a screw.

I don't actually see a box there, just a hole with a bracket.  Can you provide a pic that actually shows the box?

So there is no actual box, which I know is not code. The two threaded studs are where the fan bracket would attach but the right stud is all jangled and can't accept a screw. I was hoping I could just replace the part with the two threaded studs but I dont see a way to get that out. I also can't seem to get the brace to spin to remove it. Is there a trick to this or is it just old and needs more pressure?

Fan must have solid mount to the ceiling frame studs, otherwise you are facing a disaster.
Fixing the broken one is not recommended.
Since there is no access from above it was installed from underneath, and you can replace the old one,.

The current box is one of the expannding rods that fit within two joists. I try turning it to loosen it but it doesn't seem to turn. Any ideas?
